# Invalid Authorization Code auth_code_not_found in OAuth2

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

Hi guy I have a simple diagram to explain what I to achieve
first want to authenticate OAuth with mobile because mobile cant receive a callback from auth server so I need to create new simple node server for handle authentication code and get real token everything just fine until getting real token I already send code

[image]

you will see URL that console log print
already attach code in URL
I dint know issue come from guess because different referer who getting and obtain code
because I try to use only server:9000 getting and obtain access token is work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we dont need server for obtain token just only external browser and deeplink

here solove workflow

1. native trigger external browser
2. browser send authentication request to auth server
3. authserver send authorization back to browser
4. browser trigger some address that associate to app with deeplinking also passs auth code with query param
5. native capture  auth token then send code to auth server for obtain access_token
6. auth server send access token back to native
7. native store access token in secure storage like keychain and shared preference

[image]